# EE2 JS variables

Tags: ee2, control-panel, javascript

I am writing a module that will require a lot of javascript for ajax and instead of building this in the mcp file I wish to do this as straight js files and include them.

I know that I will need to post data back using the XID and this can be done in pure JS, as per:
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/171401/

now that's great, i can use EE.XID in JS but can i get any other variables, eg base url etc?

if so is there a list as i cannot even find the EE.XID documentation.

Answer (score 1):

OK I have found them.

I basically dumped the EE var into the console and took a look - dont know why i didnt think about that..

so heres a list of variable that can be used:

```
BASE 
CP_SIDEBAR_STATE
PATH_CP_GBL_IMG
SESS_TIMEOUT
SESS_TYPE
THEME_URL
XID
XID_TIMEOUT
```

hope this helps others